# Do Stormtroopers or Imperial officers receive vacation?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In some of the episodes of [Rebels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels) it seems like some of the Imperial officers and perhaps their underlings can't wait to get a promotion.  At first thought, I assumed that means more responsibilities but also more pay and vacation.  However, while I'm not a [Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) expert, I have absorbed a lot of the Star Wars media over the years and I can't recall ever seeing an Imperial officer or Stormtrooper going on vacation.

The Rebels presumably fight because they want freedom from tyranny for the Star Wars galaxy and whatnot.  But it seems like the desire to serve the Empire must come from its wealth, but perhaps the soldiers are too busy fighting to take a vacation.

**Are there any Canon references to vacation of Stormtroopers or Imperial officers?  Any Legends references?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Imperial officers certainly get leave time

However, the canon novel *Lost Stars* indicates that, at least for career-focused Imperial officers (which is a slightly redundant turn of phrase, if you catch my meaning), using it is discouraged:

> "I've accrued seven weeks of leave time, sir. I strongly doubt I will use them all."
>
> Ideal Imperial officers used no leave time whatsoever, unless they had to recover from a serious illness or injury. Ciena had never asked to take a single day until now.
>
> <sup>*Lost Stars* Chapter 18</sup>

Although I'm not certain if this luxury also extends to Stormtroopers (at least, I'm not certain of any explicit mention of it), one would certainly expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways other than official leave to get leave.

In the novelization of *Rogue One* there's a bit about Tarkin having no trouble using the Death Star on the Scarif base because he's annoyed with Imperial officers and their troops treating being assigned there as a vacation.

In the real world, many militaries have assignments like that: for instance, you might have to put in a few hours on duty, but the rest of the day you get to enjoy the local hospitality, or whatever. Compared to your normal responsibilities, it's a vacation.

Presumably there are posts all over the Star Wars galaxy where this is the case. Scarif was a secret location and relatively heavily defended so there wasn't much of a threat to personnel on the ground so once they clocked off for the day they headed to the beach.

Comment: I'm not really sure this answers the question. Tarkin muses that it's *like* a vacation resort, not that it actually is one. I'm sure there are many plum assignments but they aren't leave